# How to prevent websites from storing offline data in Firefox 57

Tags: firefox, firefox-57

This appears to be either a long-running bug or an "unintended feature".

Certain websites store data for offline use. I don't know why, but I do know that this data is separate from cookies and cache.

In Firefox 57, under Site Data, one can see which websites have store how much data. However there is no option to *prevent* websites from storing said data in the first place.

Most online tutorials date from 2010 to 2014, and mention `about:permissions`, which no longer exists.

I have configured `offline-apps.allow_by_default` to `false`, and o`ffline-apps.quota.warn` to `0`. Now all I get is a message of "[website] is now using more than 0MB of offline data storage". I am not getting a request for permission as I expected. I still cannot *prevent* websites from storing data.

How can I *prevent* websites from storing offline data in Firefox 57?

Comment: Related - [*How to change the default local storage settings in Firefox?*](https://superuser.com/questions/1272531/how-to-change-the-default-local-storage-settings-in-firefox)

Comment: You might add why such a function would be important to you.

Answer (score 2):

Open a new tab in Firefox and in the address bar type:

about:config

Press enter. Agree to the warning notice. In the search field, start typing:

browser.cache.offline.enable

Change its value to "false" to disable the offline cache.

https://www.privacytools.io/#about_config

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question refers to data independent of cookies and cache, e.g. `localStorage` and `IndexedDB`. The option you suggest only toggles the HTTP cache, which has little to nothing to do with websites intentionally storing offline data.

Comment: For example, [a quick test](https://demo.agektmr.com/storage/) shows that IndexedDB and localStorage persist even with your suggested option toggled.

Answer (score 0):

While it should be possible to disable offline data entirely (mostly, localStorage and IndexedDB), this has the potential to break the websites that depend on it. If you still wish to do so, the relevant config entries are `dom.storage.enabled`/`dom.storage.default_quota` (quota to 0 shows the API as enabled but full, which could break either fewer or more sites depending on the site's error handling) and `dom.indexedDB.enabled`.

Generally, a better idea is to clear the data on browser exit. While this still allows tracking within the same session, it will reduce long-term tracking.

To do this, head to `about:preferences` (or menu => Options), Privacy & Security tab. Under History, select **Use custom settings for history**. Tick **Clear history when Firefox closes**, and head into its Settings to tick **Offline Website Data**. You might also want to untick browsing history, etc., if you want to keep those.

[image: Gif video of the process]

---

Another thing that some websites will use is a Service Worker. I believe the above delete-on-close should work to clear Service Worker caches, but it's rather more difficult to test. If you want, you can disable them entirely through `about:config`'s `dom.serviceWorkers.enabled` option. Note that this runs into the same potential issues as disabling other storage methods entirely: some sites simply will not work without them.